# Precision in C++

Tags: c++

So I've seen the few other posts here and elsewhere regarding increasing decimal precision, but for some odd reason I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Here's what I've got:

```
//Euler's Method Approximation

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i=1;
    double h;
    double x_n;
    double y_n;


    cout << "Enter n: " ;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl << "Enter h: " ;
    cin >> h;
    cout << endl << "Enter x_0: ";
    cin >> x_n;
    cout << endl << "Enter y_0: ";
    cin >> y_n;

    cout << "n=" << i << " x=" << x_n << " y=" << y_n << endl;
    ++i;

    while(i<n+1)
    {
        y_n = y_n + 3*x_n*h*y_n;        
        x_n = x_n + h;
        cout << "n=" << i << " x=" << x_n << " y=" << setprecision(6) << y_n << endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I apologize for the mess. Just threw this down under a time crunch, but now I've got more time to look at it. What could I be doing wrong? The mathematics definitely generates decimals to arbitrary precision depending on input, and all the variable types are as they should be. Even have the iomanip library in there. Any pointers? ( Still only prints out to the millionths )

Comment: works fine for me, you'll have to be more specific regarding the i/o

Comment: Run it with n=8 h=.2 , x_0 = 1, y_0 = 8. You get decimals with 6 places towards n=8?

Comment: yup: http://ideone.com/GKvznS

Comment: Put `std::fixed` at the end of `cout << "n=" << i << " x=" << x_n << " y=" << setprecision(6) << y_n << fixed << endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `std::fixed` at the end of `cout << "n=" << i << " x=" << x_n << " y=" << setprecision(6) << y_n << fixed << endl;` as suggested by @40two in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For `ofstream` you can use the `precision` method, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/